# Google SEO vs. Bing SEO

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords

I was wondering if anyone has had this problem before.

What is happening is that Keyword Phrase; "**A B C**", has been optimized for Page; "**A B C**." The Keyword Phrase; "**D F G**," has been optimized for page "**D F G**."

On **Google**; when you search; "**A B C**", page; "*A B C*" yeilds a page 1 result.  When you search; "**D F G**," page; "**A B C**" yields a page 1 result, while "**D F G**" yeilds no results.

What could be the reason that page "**A B C**" is stealing the thunder? Also, when you do an exact quote search for "**D F G**,"  page "**A B C**" still comes up, and the quote of "**D F G**" does not appear once on the page.

Also with Bing everything is working as expected.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the specific phrases and evaluating the pages themselves. Google is fairly simple to understand, however, there are a lot of moving parts. Still, if you do a proper and plain job of SEO, then the results should be simple to understand and adjust.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the value of the page. If you Google for "tools" you're more likely to get "Home Depot" than search results with a wall of tools.

I have some theatre companies I work with. If you search for some of the actors who have played parts, you will get the theatre company production page and not the actor's page.

As far as Bing goes, well, there's a reason Bing loses money for Microsoft while Google gains billions every year.

Comment: You get credit for the Bing losing money for Microsoft comment. It is amazing how many years it has been. With Microsoft, this should not have been a problem except for the culture.

Comment: Definitely noted. I do not think this is the issue though. Our page is the only page that comes up without the quote. Every other Google result has the actual quote on the page or in the URL.